# NSString out of scope

Tags: cocoa

I used the codes below to set a NSString

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface AppController : NSObject
{


    NSString *myString;


}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *myString;
@end

#import "AppController.h"


@implementation AppController
@synthesize myString;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

    NSString *zs0= [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"abc"];
    myString =[zs0 retain];
    [zs0 release];//breakpoint

}

- (void)dealloc {


    [myString release];


    [super dealloc];
}




@end
```

when I check the value of myString at the breakpoint
it always said 'out of scope'

Welcome any comment

Comment: Sometimes the debugger does that.  Type "po myString" in the console window and see what you get.

Comment: (The retain/release is a bit redundant.  You could scrap the pair of them.  Or, my favorite, do `self.myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"abc"];`.)

Comment: (And that's my final word on the subject.)

Comment: It's recommended that you don't call accessors in an `init` method. You should set the value of the ivars directly.

Comment: same result, if I define myString before the codes 'myString =[zs0 retain];' rather than define as the member of object AppController, everything is ok

Comment: I just tried it with self.myString = [NSString stringWithString:@"abc"]; with myString being a synthesized, retained property.  I set a breakpoint right after in applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions (iOS app) and the debugger said it had "abc" value.

Comment: in my case, it works on ios, but reported error on cocoa/mac osx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You don't need the temp variable zs0 - just assign it to the property
2. You don't need initWithFormat since you're not formatting.
3. You don't need to alloc the string - if you call [NSString stringWithString] it will autorelease it and then when you assign it to a (retain) property, it will retain it.
4. You're over retaining.  You alloc the string which gives it a retain count of 1, then you retain it which gives it 2, then you assign it to a retained property which retains it again.

One simple way is:

```
self.myString = [NSString stringWithString:@"abc"];
```

That will create a string that's autoreleased (not created with alloc, copy by convention) and then the property will retain it.

Comment: same result, if I define myString before the codes 'myString =[zs0 retain];' rather than define as the member of object AppController, everything is ok

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using initWithFormat if you aren't using a format?Next, why even allocate zs0 if you aren't going to use it? Just set myString to what you want it to be.
Thus, your code should look like this:

```
myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: @"abc"];
```

Try that and everything should work.

Comment: same result, if I define myString before the codes 'myString =[zs0 retain];' rather than define as the member of object AppController, everything is ok